# How should i insert mulitple values in one lookup column by id and version should not be increase

Tags: sharepoint-online

```
let temp: any[] = [];
  // temp = temp.concat(linkage.map((d: any) => d.value));
   let a = linkage.map((d:any)=> {let obj = { LookupId: d.value }
    temp.push(obj)
  })
   
    const web = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/`;
        const url = `${web}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('PublishedRequest')/items(${id})/ValidateUpdateListItem`;
        const body: string = JSON.stringify({
          formValues: [
           
            {
              FieldName: "DocumentType",
              FieldValue: documentType.value,
            },
            {
              FieldName: "CategoryId",
              FieldValue: String(category.value),
            },
            {
              FieldName: "BusinessProcessId",
              FieldValue: `${businessProcess.value}`,
            },
            {
              FieldName: "WorkflowInstructionsId",
              FieldValue: `${workflowIns.value}`,
            },
            {
              FieldName: "CustomKeywords",
              FieldValue: keyword,
            },
            {
              FieldName: "SubCategory",
              FieldValue: String(subCategory.value),
            },
            {
              FieldName: "Linkage",
              //FieldValue: `${[{"results" : temp}]}`
              FieldValue: JSON.stringify(temp)
            }
          ],
          bNewDocumentUpdate: true,
        });
   
    const response = await props.context.spHttpClient.post(
      url,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "odata-version": "3.0",
        },
        body: body,
      }
    );
```

In above code I don't want to update version by updating values, category id, businessprocess id these are my lookup column but they are single value lookup column and my linkage is multiple value lookup column by using this code my multiple value are not inserting. So how can I insert multiple value in one lookup column by using this code?